# Run 'create-react-app' failed

Tags: reactjs

I came across the following problem

I ref [react-app tutorials](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#getting-started) to create a react-app demo. When I run `create-react-app my-app` command, it failed.

[image]

After that, I have changed npm mirror to `taobao.org`(in China). But it also failed.

`npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org`

So, how to slove the problem.

Comment: why are you not pointing your registry to default `http://registry.npmjs.org/`? Can you please try `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` once and then try creating a new reactJs app through `create-react-app` command.

Comment: I tried your method，but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you know what version of node you are running? `node -v`

Comment: My node version is `v6.11.0`

Comment: Try uninstalling Yarn? Then it will attempt to use npm. Maybe it will work better.

Comment: I haven't had this problem, but I've read people have had success by updating their node version, or by uninstalling yarn like @DanAbramov said.

Answer (score 1):

1. I uninstall yarn and reinstall .
2. Reinstall node
3. Reinstall react-app.
4. Need administrator's permission to install react-app in CMD.

With the method, I install react-app successfully!

Comment: ohh. I didn't notice you were using yarn for managing your packages. I'm a Node package manager(NPM) fan :). Although I've heard about yarn as well. Glad that you were able to solve it by your own efforts.

Comment: I had a similar error and managed to fix it by following the steps above, plus removing the yarn config folder: `rm -rf ~/.config/yarn`. See: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1155#issuecomment-353568873.